# How would I write this query that includes joins in CodeIgniter's query builder?

Tags: php, codeigniter

The query I'm trying to write is

```
SELECT Equipment.Name, Equipment.EquipmentTag, LoanedOut.StudentNumber, LoanedOut.DueDate 
FROM Equipment, LoanedOut 
WHERE Equipment.EquipmentRecordID = LoanedOut.EquipmentRecordID AND LoanedOut.StudentNumber = 040828055
```

I can't figure out how to do it using the query builder for codeigniter, the best I have so far is

```
$this->db->select('Equipment.Name, Equipment.EquipmentTag, LoanedOut.StudentNumber, LoanedOut.DueDate');
$this->db->from('Equipment e, LoanedOut l');
$this->db->join('l', 'e.EquipmentRecordID = l.EquipmentRecordID')->join('l', 'l.StudentNumber', $studentNumber);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you what you want//

```
 $sql = 'SELECT e.Name,e.EquipmentTag,l.StudentNumber,l.DueDate FROM Equipment e LEFT JOIN LoanedOut l ON e.EquipmentRecordID = l.EquipmentRecordID WHERE l.StudentNumber = "040828055"'
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thank you very much